# EntityFramework Query select (contains) (all villages that have farmers which plant apples)

Tags: entity-framework

```
village(id, list(farmers))
farmer(id, List(fruits));
fruit(id,name).
```

How would I write a query that selects all villages that have the fruit with ID 23 (e.g. apples)?

It would be easy to write this with 2 queries. How wold you do it with one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var villages = db.Villages
          .Where(v => v.Farmaers.Any(f => f.Fruits.Any(t => t.Id == 23)));
```